# Error in logic for year comparison tool

Tags: android, date, if-statement, logic

I'm attempting to create a tool that compares the current year to the year that an event took place and then allows the user to guess how many years it has been since that event occurred. For example, the inaugural FRC Championship took place in 1992. The current year is 2015. The user guesses that it took place 23 years ago, which is correct.

So, in my mind the code would look like this...

```
  public class Credits extends Activity {
    int inaugural = 1992;
    int guess;
    int differenceInYears;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int output;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_credits);
        final EditText yearGuess=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtYearGuess);
        Button go = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);
        final TextView result = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult));
        go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int userGuess= Integer.parseInt(yearGuess.getText().toString());
                differenceInYears = year - inaugural;
                output = userGuess - differenceInYears;

                if (output < 1) {
                    result.setText("Guess again! You guessed too low!");
                }

                else if (output == 1) {
                    result.setText("You're REALLY close!");

                }

                else if (output == -1) {
                    result.setText("You're REALLY close!");

                }

                else if (output > 1) {
                    result.setText("Guess again! You guessed too high!");

                }

                else {
                    result.setText("Good job! You're an FRC Genious!");

                }
            }

        });
     }
    }
```

...however, the values continue to come out wrong when tested. What am I missing here? Is there something wrong with my math? or code? or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the logic of your if-statement. When the user guesses correctly, "output" should equal 0 which would get caught by your first condition.

Comment: Yeah. I just now realized that too by using the debug variable probe tool. Didn't even know that a tool like that existed until I accidentally clicked it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple logic error.

```
if (output < 1) {
                    result.setText("Guess again! You guessed too low!");
                }
```

should have been...

```
if (output < -1) {
                    result.setText("Guess again! You guessed too low!");
                }
```

Just forgot to make the low comparison negative.